# Magento 2.3 Authorize.net payment Suspected Fraud to Deny Payment not going

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, payment-gateway, authorize.net, suspected-fraud

I am using **authorize.net capture** as default magento `payment gateway` in **magento 2.3** and I have one order coming suspected fraud. but when I will suspected fraud to deny payment and I see error but I can't process continue to **Deny Payment**

[image]
[image]
and error like:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAdditionalInformation() on boolean in 
/cache/vendor/magento/module-authorizenet-acceptjs/Gateway/Request/VoidDataBuilder.php:50
```

and error coming below file function:

> vendor/magento/module-authorizenet-acceptjs/Gateway/Request/VoidDataBuilder.php

```
public function build(array $buildSubject): array
{
    $paymentDO = $this->subjectReader->readPayment($buildSubject);
    $payment = $paymentDO->getPayment();
    $transactionData = [];

    if ($payment instanceof Payment) {
        $authorizationTransaction = $payment->getAuthorizationTransaction();
        $refId = $authorizationTransaction->getAdditionalInformation('real_transaction_id'); //here error line
        if (empty($refId)) {
            $refId = $authorizationTransaction->getParentTxnId();
        }

        $transactionData['transactionRequest'] = [
            'transactionType' => self::REQUEST_TYPE_VOID,
            'refTransId' => $refId
        ];
    }

    return $transactionData;
}
```

I know here some one ask this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/309805/86511) but nothing find any answer it's **magento core bug**?

i have change as per @sohelrana answer and now another error coming

> Invalid request to gateway.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code returns boolean instead of an object.

```
$payment->getAuthorizationTransaction()
```

If you look following class:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Transaction/Manager.php

```
public function getAuthorizationTransaction($parentTransactionId, $paymentId, $orderId)
{
    $transaction = false;
    if ($parentTransactionId) {
        $transaction = $this->transactionRepository->getByTransactionId(
            $parentTransactionId,
            $paymentId,
            $orderId
        );
    }

    return $transaction ?: $this->transactionRepository->getByTransactionType(
        Transaction::TYPE_AUTH,
        $paymentId,
        $orderId
    );
}
```

Check **sales_payment_transaction** table for this order. Maybe entry is missing.

**[Fix]**

Add one check before getting value. Ex:

```
if ($authorizationTransaction = $payment->getAuthorizationTransaction()) {
```

Now full method looks like:

```
public function build(array $buildSubject): array
{
    $paymentDO = $this->subjectReader->readPayment($buildSubject);
    $payment = $paymentDO->getPayment();
    $transactionData = [];

    if ($payment instanceof Payment) {
        if ($authorizationTransaction = $payment->getAuthorizationTransaction()) {
            $refId = $authorizationTransaction->getAdditionalInformation('real_transaction_id');
            if (empty($refId)) {
                $refId = $authorizationTransaction->getParentTxnId();
            }

            $transactionData['transactionRequest'] = [
                'transactionType' => self::REQUEST_TYPE_VOID,
                'refTransId' => $refId
            ];
        }
    }

    return $transactionData;
}
```

Don't modify core code. Use plugin or overwrite.

Comment: thanks for answer i am checking in table if entry available or not..

Comment: how can solve this problem ?@sohel

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: i have implement your code but after this error coming `Invalid request to gateway.
` (https://prnt.sc/ruv7bi)